# Curves on a circle

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Is it possible at every point $p=(x,y)$ on the unit circle, there is a continuous curve $C_p$ passing through it, a curve which is not only the single point $p$, and all these curves are pairwise disjoint?

And there is a constant $e$, such that all these curves have length longer then $e$.

Edit:

How to prove that they must be all the same curve locally around $p$, except translated and rotated?

Comment: Sure, take for example segments of radial lines.

Comment: Similar to @AndréNicolas, pick any point in the interior of the unit disk, and draw straight lines from this point outwards. Take segments of these lines.

Comment: @lbhezbgure: Of course they are continuous. Radial lines have end points. My suggestion is purely a deformation of Andre's suggestion.

Comment: "[Segments of lines] aren't continuous, because they have endpoints" -- Do you mean *closed* curves rather than *continuous* curves? Curves are necessarily continuous according to the usual definition.

Comment: oh ok, i get it. How to prove that they must be all the smae curve except translated and rotated?

Comment: You can't prove that because it's not true.

Comment: @TonyK Give a counterexample?

Comment: Take the segments of radial lines and wiggle them a bit.

Comment: Why dont you have to wiggle them all the same, so they coincide?

Comment: Why don't I have to bend them into the shape of a smiley face either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c\in {\mathbb R}$ consider the segments
$$\sigma_c:\quad v(u):= c +\sin c\ u\qquad\bigl(-{1\over2}<u<{1\over2}\bigr)$$
in the $(u,v)$-plane. The segment $\sigma_c$ intercepts the $v$-axis at the height $c$. As $|c-c'| > {1\over 2}|\sin c-\sin c'|$ when $c\ne c'$, these segments are disjoint; and when $c=c'$ ${\rm mod}\, 2\pi$ the segments $\sigma_c$ and $\sigma_{c'}$ are parallel.

The map $w\mapsto z:=e^w$, where $w=u+iv$, $z=x+iy$, maps the strip $-{1\over2}<u<{1\over2}$  onto the annulus $e^{-1/2}<|z|<e^{1/2}$. Thereby the segments $\sigma_c$ will be mapped onto  arcs of logarithmic spirals which are disjoint when $c\ne c'$ ${\rm mod}\, 2\pi$ and noncongruent when $\sin c\ne \sin c'$.